# My app puts the phone volume to maximum

Tags: android, volume

My app puts the phone volume to maximum.

```
package com.sms;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.SmsMessage;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class SMSReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
private static final String number = "15555215556";

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
    Object[] messages = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
    SmsMessage[] sms = new SmsMessage[messages.length];

    for (int i=0; i < messages.length; i++) {
        sms[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) messages[i]);
    }
    for (SmsMessage msg : sms) {

        if (TextUtils.equals(msg.getOriginatingAddress(), number)) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "" + msg.getMessageBody(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            //AudioManager mAudioManager = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

            MediaPlayer mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.son1);
            mPlayer.setVolume(1.0f, 1.0f);
            mPlayer.start();
            abortBroadcast();
        }
    }
}
```

}

I get an error at the this.getSystemService asking me to create the getSystemService method.
Someone can help me.
thanks.

Comment: Is you class **extends** `Activity`?

Comment: No she extend BroadcastReceiver

Comment: can you post you code with `BroadcastReceiver`. may be my ans will help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this..

```
final AudioManager mAudioManager = (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
```

Try this..

```
AudioManager mAudioManager;
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
    Object[] messages = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
    SmsMessage[] sms = new SmsMessage[messages.length];

    for (int i=0; i < messages.length; i++) {
        sms[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) messages[i]);
    }
    mAudioManager = (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    for (SmsMessage msg : sms) {

        if (TextUtils.equals(msg.getOriginatingAddress(), number)) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "" + msg.getMessageBody(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            MediaPlayer mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.son1);
            mPlayer.setVolume(1.0f, 1.0f);
            mPlayer.start();
            abortBroadcast();
        }
    }
```

Or

```
    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        Object[] messages = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
        SmsMessage[] sms = new SmsMessage[messages.length];

        for (int i=0; i < messages.length; i++) {
            sms[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) messages[i]);
        }

        for (SmsMessage msg : sms) {

            if (TextUtils.equals(msg.getOriginatingAddress(), number)) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "" + msg.getMessageBody(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                AudioManager mAudioManager = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
                MediaPlayer mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.son1);
                mPlayer.setVolume(1.0f, 1.0f);
                mPlayer.start();
                abortBroadcast();
            }
        }
```

Comment: the error persists.
I still have the red underline below getSystemService

Comment: can you ple add codes or Are you using your code inside `onReceive`

Answer (score 1):

The `getSystemService()` method is derived from the `Context` abstract class. `Service` and `Activity` classes extend the `Context` class so you can call this method from their inner methods. What class do you try to call it from?

Answer (score 0):

I use this code:

```
mAudioManager = (AudioManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);                 
player = new MediaPlayer();
player = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.alert);

    if (player != null)
        {                                   
            mAudioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
            mAudioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC), AudioManager.FLAG_PLAY_SOUND);
            player.start();
        }
```

You say you're using a BroadcastReciever, this is how I get the context in a BroadcasReciever, so change the method to:

```
public class GPSStatusBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) { 

mAudioManager = (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);                 
player = new MediaPlayer();
player = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.alert);

    if (player != null)
        {                                   
            mAudioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
            mAudioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC), AudioManager.FLAG_PLAY_SOUND);
            player.start();
        }


}
```

Comment: the error persists.
I still have the red underline below getSystemService

Comment: don't call this.getSystemService put AudioManager mAudioManager = (AudioManager)context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);